# Collections.unmodifiableCollection and Collections.unmodifiableSet

Tags: java, groovy, collections, set, unmodifiable

Suppose I have the following `Set`

```
Set<String> fruits = new HashSet<String>();
fruits.add("Apple")
fruits.add("Grapes")
fruits.add("Orange")
```

If I wanted to create a defensive copy, so that if the original list is modified, the copy doesn't reflect it, I can do this:

```
Set<String> unmodifiableFruits = Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet(fruits))
```

so if I do this:

```
fruits.add("Pineapple")     
println(unmodifiableFruits)
```

`unmodifiableFruits` won't have pineapple.

or I can so this:

```
Set<String> unmodifiableFruits = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(fruits)
```

and the result is the same, `unmodifiableFruits` won't have pineapple.

**Questions:**

1. Suppose if I were passing `fruits` as an argument to a class, is the preferred method the `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()`?

The reason is, I've [read](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365119/is-using-new-in-the-constructor-always-bad) that declaring `new` in the constructor is a bad practice, if I were to use `Collections.unmodifiableSet()`, I would need to declare a `new HashSet<String>(fruits)`.

2. Why can't I do this ?

   `Collections.unmodifiableSet(fruits)`

and have it return an unmodifiable collection.

instead I have to do this:

```
Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(fruits))
```

Is it because Set is an interface and it doesn't know which implementation to return?

Comment: You _could_, but that would mean that changes to `fruits` _would_ get reflected in `unmodifiableFruits`, even though `unmodifiableFruits` can't be changed directly.

Comment: `Set<String> unmodifiableFruits = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(fruits)` won't compile.

Comment: @shmosel - Using Groovy it does. :D

Comment: @LouisWasserman - Is using `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` the proper way when passing a `set` into the constructor?

Comment: That's odd. I'm curious what it's doing under the hood. Either way, as mentioned, it will actually reflect updates to the underlying collection, as implied by the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableSet-java.util.Set-).

Comment: @shmosel - My question is though why do I have to say `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(fruits))`? Why couldn't the developers do it so that I don't have to create a `new Hashset`? WIth  `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` I don't have to create a new `HashSet`. I just pass in the collection.

Comment: @shmosel - Is it because `Set` is an interface and the `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` doesn't know what to return?

Comment: If you're suggesting there's a difference between `unmodifiableSet()` and `unmodifiableCollection()` with respect to mutability, there isn't. Unless Groovy is secretly creating a new set under the hood in your case.

Comment: Using `new` in a constructor isn't wrong as a rule, for example [this answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/365123/110799) actually names the scenario in your question as a specific example of `new` being "quite normal". Also, in Java 10, you can use [`Set.copyOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#copyOf%28java.util.Collection%29) to create an immutable set which is independent of the source collection.

Comment: @shmosel Groovy *is* secretly creating a new set under the hood. See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52068694/5221149).

Comment: It’s rather strange to ask why these `unmodifiable…` methods do not create a new set/collection in some situations, when the very purpose of these methods is to *never* create a new collection, but to return a *view* to the original collection. It would be a horrible design, if these methods were sometimes creating a new collection and sometimes not and it is even worse to hear that Groovy does exactly that, even on the language level. As @Radiodef mentioned, the Java 10 solution to get an immutable set is `copyOf` which is smart enough not copy already immutable sets.

Comment: @Holger - It's all in the interest of writing code and learning how these methods work :D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Groovy has enhanced collection methods, meaning that it has added methods to the standard collection classes.

Once of those methods is [`toSet()`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/util/Collection.html#toSet()):

> Convert a Collection to a Set. **Always returns a new Set** even if the Collection is already a Set.
>
> Example usage:
>
> ```
> def result = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3].toSet()
> assert result instanceof Set
> assert result == [1, 2, 3] as Set
> ```

When you write this:

```
Set<String> unmodifiableFruits = Collections.unmodifiableCollection(fruits)
```

it implies a `.toSet()` call to coerce the `Collection` returned by `unmodifiableCollection` into a `Set`, **implicitly copying the data**.

When you write this:

```
Set<String> unmodifiableFruits = Collections.unmodifiableSet(fruits)
```

the returned value is already a `Set`, so `toSet()` is not called, meaning that `unmodifiableFruits` and `fruits` share data.

That is why you have to explicitly copy the data when using `unmodifiableSet`, by adding `new HashSet(...)`.

> Is using `Collections.unmodifiableCollection()` the proper way when passing a set into the constructor?

***Absolutely not.*** Using `unmodifiableCollection()` and assigning to a `Set`, implicitly invoking `toSet` which copies the data, is hiding the fact that a copy is executed.

To ensure code readability, i.e. that anyone reading the code (including yourself in 3 years) will understand what it does, write the code to explicitly copy the data, using the copy-constructor.

Well, of course, unless this is an exercise in code obfuscation, in which case it's a nice misleading trick.

Comment: *To ensure code readability, i.e. that anyone reading the code (including yourself in 3 years) will understand what it does, write the code to explicitly copy the data, using the copy-constructor.* You mean use `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(fruits))` for readability?

Comment: *Absolutely not. Using unmodifiableCollection() and assigning to a Set, implicitly invoking toSet which copies the data, is hiding the fact that a copy is executed.* Why would hiding the fact the copy was executed be wrong? I think using `unmodifiableCollection()` is appropriate in some cases, take this one for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46672320/getters-for-display/46675088

Comment: @Sveta Yes to first comment. --- You should always use the `unmodifiableXxx` that matches the type you're interested in. That's why `Collections` has [8 versions of the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#i58). In the link you provided, `unmodifiableCollection` is only used when the return type is `Collection`. The fact that Groovy *silently* converts a `Collection` to a `Set`, with the hidden side-effect of copying the data, is unfortunate *(in my opinion)*.

Comment: @Sveta *"Why would hiding the fact the copy was executed be wrong?"* Because people reading your code, e.g. if they have to modify it, may misinterpret what it does. Unless you're deliberately obfuscating code, code should be a clear as possible to readers of the code, to prevent mistakes and coding errors.

Comment: Wow, I learned something about Groovy today. +1. I agree, the silent copying is very confusing.

Comment: @Sveta No one's saying `unmodifiableCollection()` isn't useful. We're saying that the implicit conversion of Collection to Set is highly deceptive, as it results in a mutable copy, instead of the immutable wrapper you'd expect at a glance.

Comment: @shmosel - Suppose if I'm stubborn and I'm determined to use `unmodifiableCollection()` despite the readability issues, even if I documented what `unmodifiableCollection()` is doing in my code, would that be better? You could make the argument that  `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(fruits))` doesn't need documentation because a reader will know what's happening.

Comment: @Sveta You can do whatever you want... I'm not sure what your question is.

Comment: @shmosel - If I used `unmodifiableCollection()` and documented what it was doing in my code, would it be better?

Comment: @Sveta It's not a question of better. They do different things, like I said.

Comment: @Sveta No, documenting the misbehavior is not a good way to get around misuse of a helper method. As shmosel already said, you're ending up with 1) a `Set`, not a `Collection`, 2) the `Set` is *mutable*, not immutable, and 3) a copy, not a wrapper. This means you're getting the entire **opposite** of what the method is supposed to give you. Very, very bad.

Comment: @Andreas - Good points. Given that `Collections.unmodifiableSet()` is more appropriate, when passing a `set` to the constructor, to make copy I would need to do  `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(fruits))`. This ensures the client can't change the collection after object creation, it's independent. As linked in my question, using `new` in the constructor is not a good idea, but in this case, is it okay?

Comment: @Sveta *"using `new` in the constructor is not a good idea"* You seem to have a terminology issue here. You cannot invoke a *constructor* without the use of the `new` keyword. --- Also, why do you believe copying a collection using `new` is not a good idea? It is the recommended way of doing it.

Comment: What I mean is suppose if I a class called `Book` and I had a `set` called `authors` in the `Book` class constructor I would say `Collections.unmodifiableSet(new HashSet<String>(authors))`. Is calling `HashSet<String>(authors))` from the Book constructor okay? See link for details of what I'm talking about. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/365119/is-using-new-in-the-constructor-always-bad

Comment: @Sveta That is about creating *new* related objects, not about copying mutable objects to isolate the data given in parameters. Unfortunately, they use the meme *"using `new` in a constructor"* to refer to this, but since creating objects and copying objects (using copy-constructor) both use the `new` operator, the meme is misleading. --- Basically, in the example you just gave, the meme says to not use `new Author("Hemmingway")` to create a *new* author object inside the `Book` constructor.

Comment: @Andreas - All questions have been answered, including the ones in the comments. Thanks!